# Jest with NestJS and async function

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

I'm trying to a test a async function of a `service` in **nestJS**.

this function is async... basically get a value (JSON) from database (using repository - TypeORM), and when successfully get the data, "transform" to a different class (DTO)...
the implementation:

```
async getAppConfig(): Promise<ConfigAppDto> {
  return this.configRepository.findOne({
    key: Equal("APPLICATION"),
  }).then(config => {
    if (config == null) {
      return new class implements ConfigAppDto {
        clientId = '';
        clientSecret = '';
      };
    }
    return JSON.parse(config.value) as ConfigAppDto;
  });
}
```

using a controller, I checked that this worked ok.
Now, I'm trying to use Jest to do the tests, but with no success...
My problem is how to mock the `findOne` function from `repository`..

**Edit**: I'm trying to use `@golevelup/nestjs-testing` to mock `Repository`!

I already mocked the `repository`, but for some reason, the `resolve` is never called..

```
describe('getAppConfig', () => {
  const repo = createMock<Repository<Config>>();

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ConfigService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Config),
          useValue: repo,
        }
      ],
    }).compile();
  });

  it('should return ConfigApp parameters', async () => {
    const mockedConfig = new Config('APPLICATION', '{"clientId": "foo","clientSecret": "bar"}');
    repo.findOne.mockResolvedValue(mockedConfig);
    expect(await repo.findOne()).toEqual(mockedConfig); // ok

    const expectedReturn = new class implements ConfigAppDto {
      clientId = 'foo';
      clientSecret = 'bar';
    };
    expect(await service.getAppConfig()).toEqual(expectedReturn);

    // jest documentation about async -> https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous
    // return expect(service.getAppConfig()).resolves.toBe(expectedReturn);
  });
})
```

- the `expect(await repo.findOne()).toEqual(mockedConfig);` works great;
- `expect(await service.getAppConfig()).toEqual(expectedReturn);` got a timeout => `Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout`;

using debug, I see that the `service.getAppConfig()` is called, the `repository.findOne()` too, but the `.then` of repository of findOne is never called.

**Update**: I'm trying to mock the repository using `@golevelup/nestjs-testing`, and for some reason, the mocked result don't works on service.
If I mock the repository using only `jest` (like code below), the test works... so, I think my real problem it's `@golevelup/nestjs-testing`.

```
...
provide: getRepositoryToken(Config),
useValue: {
  find: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([new Config()])
},
...
```

Comment: What does your ConfigService look like?

Comment: It's the first part of the code in the question: `async getAppConfig(): Promise<ConfigAppDto>`

Comment: My question was on the implementation of the ConfigService ;) How do you load the env vars? Can you show us?

Comment: i don't get! no env vars used! the `ConfigService.APP_CONFIG_KEY` its just a static string with value `"APPLICATION"`. Almost the entire ConfigService it's here... the only part that I don't included its the static string, imports, and constructor (with `@InjectRepository`, because this is not related with the problem... I will update the code)

Comment: What if you comment ` expect(await repo.findOne()).toEqual(mockedConfig); // ok`? Maybe jest is mocking only in the first time, just guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, my real problem is how I'm mocking the `Repository` on `NestJS`.
For some reason, when I mock using the `@golevelup/nestjs-testing`, weird things happens!

I really don't found a good documentation about this on `@golevelup/nestjs-testing`, so, I gave up using it.

My solution for the question was to use only `Jest` and `NestJS` functions... the result code was:

**Service**:

```
// i'm injecting Connection because I need for some transactions later;
constructor(@InjectRepository(Config) private readonly configRepo: Repository<Config>, private connection: Connection) {}

async getAppConfig(): Promise<ConfigApp> {
  return this.configRepo.findOne({
    key: Equal("APPLICATION"),
  }).then(config => {
    if (config == null) {
      return new ConfigApp();
    }
    return JSON.parse(config.value) as ConfigApp;
  })
}
```

**Test**:

```
describe('getAppConfig', () => {
  const configApi = new Config();
  configApi.key = 'APPLICATION';
  configApi.value = '{"clientId": "foo", "clientSecret": "bar"}';

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ConfigAppService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Config),
          useValue: {
            findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(new
            Config("APPLICATION", '{"clientId": "foo", "clientSecret": "bar"}')),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: getConnectionToken(),
          useValue: {},
        }
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<ConfigAppService>(ConfigAppService);
  });

  it('should return ConfigApp parameters', async () => {
    const expectedValue: ConfigApp = new ConfigApp("foo", "bar");

    return service.getAppConfig().then(value => {
      expect(value).toEqual(expectedValue);
    })
  });
})
```

some sources utilized for this solution:
https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/tree/master/apps/typeorm-sample

Answer (score 1):

I think `expect(await repo.findOne()).toEqual(mockedConfig);` works because you mocked it, so it returns right away.
In the case of `expect(await service.getAppConfig()).toEqual(expectedReturn);`, you did not mock it so it is probably taking more time, thus the `it` function returns before the `Promise` resolved completely.

The comments you posted from jest documentation should do the trick if you mock the call to `getAppConfig()`.

```
service.getAppConfig = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(someFakeValue))
```

or

```
spyOn(service, 'getAppConfig').and.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(fakeValue))
```

Comment: but I don't wanna mock `getAppConfig` function! I wanna test this function... I mocked the `findOne` because internally, the getAppConfig use this. About taking more time, I already configured Jest for timeout after 60 seconds, and still, the timeout occur, because the `then` is never called.

Comment: Ok, and if you try the example from jest documentation ?
`return expect(service.getAppConfig()).resolves.toBe(expectedReturn);`

Comment: I already tried the example from jest documentation: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:`

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63525676/12482799) from [@roberto-correia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4794469/roberto-correia) made me wonder if there must be something wrong with the way we are using `createMock` from the package `@golevelup/nestjs-testing`.

It turns out that the reason why the method exceeds the execution time has to do with the fact that `createMock` does not implement the mocking, and does not return anything, unless told to do so.

To make the method work, we have to make the mocked methods resolve something at the beginning of the test:

```
usersRepository.findOneOrFail.mockResolvedValue({ userId: 1, email: "some-random-email@email.com" });
```

A basic working solution:

```js
describe("UsersService", () => {
  let usersService: UsersService;
  const usersRepository = createMock<Repository<User>>();

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          useValue: usersRepository,
        },
    }).compile();

    usersService = module.get(UsersService);
  });

  it("should be defined", () => {
    expect(usersService).toBeDefined();
  });
  it("finds a user", async () => {
    usersRepository.findOne.mockResolvedValue({ userId: 1, email: "some-random-email@email.com" });

    expect(await usersRepository.findOne()).toBe({ userId: 1, email: "some-random-email@email.com" });
  });
});
```